# Cannot send messages using Microsoft Bot Emulator

Tags: asp.net, botframework

Version 3.5.29

The emulator at first is supposed to return a response with the number of characters of a user input string. However even after using the default endpoint url which is http://localhost:3979/api/messages, whenever inputting a string, the message is not sent.

**What appears in the log is:**

```
[04:31:00] Emulator listening on http://[::]:55944  
[04:31:01] Failed to start ngrok: undefined  
[04:31:01] ngrok may already be running in a different process. ngrok's free tier allows only one instance at a time per host.  
[04:31:01] Checking for new version...  
[04:31:02] Application is up to date.
```

Comment: Run your application :D

Comment: @BobSwager My Application is running :D

Comment: What happens when you write to your bot ? This output appears when bot updates the conversation.

Comment: @BobSwager so when I open the emulator and connect with the endpoint it should trigger internally and check with the connection which is not happening. Thus when I type any message and Send. It is not getting sent and I am not getting any response back

Comment: Debug it. Insert break points.

Comment: Have you supplied the Microsoft App Id and Microsoft App Password in the emulator?  (for local debugging, it is not required to set the appid and password).  When you run the project, a browser window should open.  Did it open to http://localhost:3979?

Comment: @EricDahlvang Yes it opened to localhost:3979 and I have not applied Microsoft App Id and Password as it was not required in local

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem.  I tried changing the path to ngrok, renaming ngrok, having ngrok running, having ngrok not running.  Maybe looking over where the error message comes from will help you diagnose the issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/c014d0494cd4eaefa5e1b7d1fd6e745c1c2ad504/src/server/botFrameworkService.ts#L120

Comment: @EricDahlvang An update my emulator is on a `Windows 10 GDE apps Lab machine` and I am taking remote and trying to run the `Bot application` there is that an issue?

Comment: @saikatmukherjee what do you mean by "i am taking remote"?

Comment: @EricDahlvang Remote Desktop Connection to this machine